# What is the best variant for appending a new line in a text file?

Tags: file-io, rust

I am using this code to append a new line to the end of a file:

```
let text = "New line".to_string();

let mut option = OpenOptions::new();
option.read(true);
option.write(true);
option.create(true);

match option.open("foo.txt") {
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Error");
    }
    Ok(mut f) => {
        println!("File opened");
        let size = f.seek(SeekFrom::End(0)).unwrap();
        let n_text = match size {
            0 => text.clone(),
            _ => format!("\n{}", text),
        };
        match f.write_all(n_text.as_bytes()) {
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Write error");
            }
            Ok(_) => {
                println!("Write success");
            }
        }

        f.sync_all();
    }
}
```

It works, but I think it's too difficult. I found `option.append(true);`, but if I use it instead of `option.write(true);` I get "Write error".

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but `.to_owned()` is faster than `.to_string()`, and is the preferred alternative unless you want to stringify some Show-implementing type.

Comment: Thanks. I will use it.

Comment: Since [specialize ToString for str](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32586), `.to_string()` is as fast as `.to_owned()`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Using [`OpenOptions::append`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.append) is the clearest way to append to a file:

```
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .append(true)
        .open("my-file")
        .unwrap();

    if let Err(e) = writeln!(file, "A new line!") {
        eprintln!("Couldn't write to file: {}", e);
    }
}
```

As of Rust 1.8.0 ([commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/42f4dd047af2de895df2754f7222b39f10cb6205)) and [RFC 1252](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1252-open-options.md), `append(true)` implies `write(true)`. This should not be a problem anymore.

Before Rust 1.8.0, you must use **both** `write` and `append` — the first one allows you to write bytes into a file, the second specifies where the bytes will be written.

Comment: Is it possible to "append" to the top as well? (so adding a line **above** the first line)

Comment: @Corel [How can I prepend a line to the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43441166/155423)

Comment: What's the behavior of just the write mode (not appending) on EOF?

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 From [`OpenOptions::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.write) "*If the file already exists, any write calls on it will overwrite its contents, without truncating it.*"

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution to accomplish the _opposite_ of what OP is discussing, I'd like to simply write to a file multiple times, without appending. My text file doesn't exist before the code is ran, so I want my code to create the file, and then non-additively write to it.

Here's how I instantiate my file object:

```rust
let mut output_txt_file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).create(true).append(false).open(output_txt_filename).unwrap();
```

This doesn't work though, as despite setting append to false, the text file continually grows with each successive call to `writeln`.

Comment: @RaleighL. in that case, you'd want to [`rewind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.rewind) your file.