# How to append to an existing CSV file?

Tags: csv, rust

As an example, when the below code is run, each time the previous `test.csv` file is overwritten with a new one. How to append to `test.csv` instead of overwriting it?

```
extern crate csv;

use std::error::Error;
use std::process;

fn run() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let file_path = std::path::Path::new("test.csv");
    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_path(file_path).unwrap();

    wtr.write_record(&["City", "State", "Population", "Latitude", "Longitude"])?;
    wtr.write_record(&["Davidsons Landing", "AK", "", "65.2419444", "-165.2716667"])?;
    wtr.write_record(&["Kenai", "AK", "7610", "60.5544444", "-151.2583333"])?;
    wtr.write_record(&["Oakman", "AL", "", "33.7133333", "-87.3886111"])?;

    wtr.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = run() {
        println!("{}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

Will the append solution work if the file does not yet exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best variant for appending a new line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684624/what-is-the-best-variant-for-appending-a-new-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: How does a `csv` file differs from any other file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [csv](https://crates.io/crates/csv) crate provides [`Writer::from_writer`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0/csv/struct.Writer.html#method.from_writer) so you can use anything, which implements [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html). When using [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30684735/3131852) from [*What is the best variant for appending a new line in a text file?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684624) shows a solution:

> Using [`OpenOptions::append`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.append) is the clearest way to append to a file

```
let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
    .write(true)
    .append(true)
    .open("test.csv")
    .unwrap();
let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(file);
```

> Will the append solution work if the file does not yet exist?

Just add `create(true)` to the `OpenOptions`:

```
let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
    .write(true)
    .create(true)
    .append(true)
    .open("test.csv")
    .unwrap();
let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(file);
```